# Subtracting a quantity with another quantity in two differentes tables in Vb

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

All is in the title.
I'm using access as my database and vb as my programming Language.

Here's my code for copying a datas table into another but i want to use my SELECT INTO Syntax with another Syntax for subtracting.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    provider = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source="
    dataFile = "C:\Users\Panda\Desktop\Test\AppMag\AppMag\Magasindb.accdb;Cache Authentication=True"

    connString = provider & dataFile
    myConnection.ConnectionString = connString
    myConnection.Open()

    Dim str1 As String

    str1 = "INSERT INTO Commandes_ok (Nom_commande_o, Nom_commande_o2, Nombre_commande_o, Nombre_commande_o2) Values (?, ?, ?, ?)"

    Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(str1, myConnection)

    cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("commande1", CType(cmd1textbox.Text, String)))
    cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("commande2", CType(cmd2textbox.Text, String)))
    cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("Amount1", CType(amount1textbox.Text, String)))
    cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("Amount2", CType(amount2textbox.Text, String)))

    Try
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        cmd.Dispose()
        myConnection.Close()

        cmd1textbox.Clear()
        amount1textbox.Clear()
        cmd2textbox.Clear()
        amount2textbox.Clear()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```

I have a quantity named "nombre_article" from article table and when the customer send a request it copy it into another table named "Commandes".

In "Commandes" the request in pending until the admin send his ok and then the data from "Commandes" goes next to "Commandes_ok" that's where my problem is ! I want to subtract [Nombre_commande] and [Nombre_commandes2] which are in "Commandes" with the initial inventory [nombre_article] for the selected article from "article" while copying it into "Commandes_ok"

Here's my access db :

[article]

{ PRIM -> Id_article : AutoNumber FOREIGN KEY -> ID_commande : AutoNumber }

[Commandes]

{ PRIM -> ID_commande : AutoNumber }

[Commandes_ok]

{ PRIM -> ID_commande_o : AutoNumber FOREIGN KEY -> ID_commande : AutoNumber FOREIGN KEY -> ID_user : AutoNumber }

Comment: That's a lot of info for saying "All is in the title".  :)  What have you tried with the SELECT INTO?  More information is needed because it seems like you need to **join multiple tables** to get the fields you need, but it is not clear precisely how the [Commandes], [Artcile] and [Commandes_ok] tables are related--what are the **primary and foreign keys**?  Please edit your question and provide these details.

Comment: Also, the code does not appear to be very helpful since it does not provide insight into necessary details of the tables and columns.  The question is more about joining and updating tables with SQL statement and not about the code.  Unless the problem is with the code itself, then don't post entire blocks of code.  See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: [article] 
{
 PRIM -> Id_article : AutoNumber
 FOREIGN KEY -> ID_commande : AutoNumber
 
}

[Commandes]

{
 PRIM -> ID_commande : AutoNumber
 

[Commandes_ok]

{
 PRIM -> ID_commande_o : AutoNumber
 FOREIGN KEY -> ID_commande : AutoNumber
 FOREIGN KEY -> ID_user : AutoNumber
 
}

[user]

{
 PRIM -> ID_user : AutoNumber
 
}                                                        @CPerkins

Comment: Okay, that provides some more info, but it is messy.  As I said in my previous comment, you should **edit** the question and add the info there.  That also gives you the ability to format the information in a better way. Part of using Stack Overflow is the expectation that you apply effort to format and edit your question to make it useful to others. Also, I just realized that "SELECT INTO" syntax refers to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb208934(v=office.12).aspx which is for _creating new_ tables.  I suppose you instead meant the "INSERT... SELECT" statement.

Comment: You also included information about the [user] table, but there is no information about that in your code or your question.  Is there a user ID on your form?  It also helps to have your code _self-document_ what you are doing by giving meaningful name to control and such... not TextBox1.

Comment: @CPerkins  sorry i just edit my question with what you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

The details are still not sufficient to give a complete answer.  The question is about subtracting quantities from two different tables, but nowhere does it specify precisely **where the results should be stored**, nor does it specify **where to get the [ID_commande] value**.  It is not clear how the TextBox values relate to the tables, etc.  Are values already in the tables or are they being specified in the TextBoxes?  It is confusing.  If you need more information about INSERT INTO... SELECT then search for and read online documentation.

```
INSERT INTO [Commandes_ok] (Nom_commande_o, Nom_commande_o2, Nombre_commande_o, Nombre_commande_o2, UNKNOWN_COLUMN)
SELECT ?, ?, ?, ?, 
    [article].[nombre_article] - ([Commandes].[Nombre_commande] + [Commandes].[Nombre_commandes2]) As Subtraction
FROM [Commandes] INNER JOIN [article]
    ON [Commandes].ID_commande = [article].ID_commande
WHERE [Commandes].ID_commande = ?
```